# Shipment Id from Amazom SP API?

Tags: python-3.x, amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

AMAZON-SP-API to pull data from amazon's seller account.Can anybody tell me how to get shipment id and FNSKU from API?. I pulled data from orders and catalog API but did not found any shipment id related to it.Neither the documentation lists the API response variables.